# Kendo UI-single column,multi column search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I did a some Google about kendoui column search and feel no exact answer for me so i am posting it here. Please help or guide me where i can find my requirement.

I am going to integrate Kendoui Grid to load huge amount of data from my database, with that I wants to have single as well multi column search functionality in the grid.

My requirement us when a user key in their search value then the grid should filter the value using **single column as well multi column search** like the below image [image]

I wants to implement the same search in kendo ui.

I know kendoui has filter functionality but, I exactly wants the functionality like the below.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is exactly what I would need and still did not find a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter) method of the grid's data source to perform filtering. Something like this:

```
grid.dataSource.filter( { 
   // display items that meet any of the conditions
   logic: "or",
   // filter conditions
   filters: [
     { field: "CompanyName", operator: "contains", value: "searchstring" },
     { field: "Country", operator: "contains", value: "searchstring" }
   ]
});
```